# Generate Nested json data from two database tables

Tags: c#, json

```
#table1#
pid  property   address
1    property1  Ashfield
2    property2  Burwood

#table2#
id  images pid
1   img1   1
2   img2   1
3   img3   2
```

How can I generate json data like below from above table using c# using asp.net?

```
property[
   {
   id: 1,
   property: property1,
   address: Ashfield,
   images:[
       images: img1,
       images: img2
   ]},
   id: 2,
   property: property2,
   address: Burwood,
   images:[
       images: img3
   ]}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var ctx = new DatabaseEntities())
            {
                var prop = from p in ctx.properties.Include("images")
                           select new
                           {
                               id = p.pid,
                               address = p.address,
                               property = p.property1,
                               images = (from img in p.images select new { images = img.images})
                           };

                var javaScriptSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(prop.ToList());

                Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
            }

Json returned from the above code is:

[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "address": "Ashfield",
      "property": "property1",
      "images": [
         {
            "images": "img1"
         },
         {
            "images": "img2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "address": "Burwood",
      "property": "property2",
      "images": [
         {
            "images": "img3"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply construct the nested object as a class, and then serialize to JSON.

As long as you can represent the JSON object as a class structure, then you can convert easilly to/from it.

```
[Table(name="address")]
public class Address{
  [Datamember(Name="images")]
  public IEnumerable<Image> Images{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer. I have this code

```
DataTable dataTable = blproperty.PropertyAll();

        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
        List > parentRow = new List > ();  
        Dictionary  childRow;  
        foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) 
        {  
            childRow = new Dictionary  ();  
            foreach(DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns) 
            {  
                childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);  
            }  
            parentRow.Add(childRow);  
        }  
        context.Response.Write(jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow));
```

Is there easy way to do modifying this?